# Tabulator - Using multiple table themes on the same page

Tags: tabulator

I can see that you can set themes for tabulator tables, from the documentation it states

"To use one of these simply include the matching CSS file instead of the default tabulator.css"

What happens if I want to have 3 tables each with a different theme?

I can see it's possible because the [documentation page](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/theme) does it but I can't see how.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible out of the box because each theme's CSS uses the same CSS selectors for the tables elements so they will all fight to style each of the tables.

I would also question why this would be necessary, generally speaking putting tables of multiple themes on the same page would create quite a jarring experience for your users and i would not recommend it.

That being said, the examples page achieves this by updating the style sheets for each of the themes to look for a specific table id rather than the generic `.tabulator` selector.

So anywhere in the stylesheet that `.tabulator` is referenced:

```css
.tabulator .tabulator-header.tabulator-header-hidden {
```

becomes for example:

```css
#bulma-theme-table .tabulator-header.tabulator-header-hidden {
```

You would also need to prefix the generic selectors later down the stylesheet, so for example:

```css
.tabulator-row.tabulator-moving {
```

would become:

```css
#bulma-theme-table .tabulator-row.tabulator-moving {
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, answers my question perfectly. As a future enhancement, it may be an idea to be able to set the table style as a property of the table (perhaps it appends the style name to the elements? Though it sounds like my use case may be a little unusual